# How to safely sign a 6 characters String?

Tags: rsa, signature

I have to decide, whether a document, which I am given, was correctly signed by a private key.

my Ideas is to sign the document id using RSA with the private key and to print the following onto the document:

```
encrypt(privateKey, id)
id
```

- Which requirenments should be fullfilled by the id, for the `encrypt(privateKey, id)` to be safe?
- Is it safe, to publish both: plaintext and the encryption, when I am choosing the paintext?
- Is there a safe cryptography method, which would allow to minimize the `encrypt(privateKey, id)` String? 
  In this special case the attacker has a very limited amount of trials (1-2) to verify whether it's fake signature is legal. When the attacker does not provide a text with a valid signature after the second trial - he is identified as a cheater. The public key is not really public here. I think, that a symmetric encryption would be better here, but the limitation to an asymmetric encryption exists due to backward compatibility reasons.

**Example**:

```
 id = ABX3193
 privateKey = 12f21te32223523fefff5z....
 encrypt(privateKey, id) = ??????
```

Comment: By using a signature operation that's designed for signing that applies proper padding. Most RSA libs have a proper RSA signature function. Don't use textbook RSA, and don't "encrypt with the private key".

Comment: Thnx for the tips! But what do you mean by don't "encrypt with the private key"? Do you mean that this is not a proper english expression, to describe the process of asymmetric encryption?

Comment: How do you derive the id from the document ? Related and more relevant to the security, how are you sure that a document with a given id cannot be modified ? The problem is that with a short id, nothing really prevents id-collisions. If that occurs, how do you know which of the two documents with the same id have been signed ?

Comment: Thnx minar, I added some text to the describtion (about a limited amount of trials for the attacker, to verify whether a text has a correct signature. When the attacker does not provide a text with a valid signature - he is identified as a cheater )

Comment: Are you sure the limitation is to asymmetric _encryption_, as opposed to (asymmetric) digital signatures? $\;\;\;$

Comment: The current system uses RSA. So two keys are distributed. They can probably be used for both: asymmetric encryption and signature.

Comment: I should add that a signature is done by "decrypting with the private key" & not "encrypting with the private key".
Though I highly advise to use some API functions & not do it by hand, as the padding should be handled properly & it would avoid you from inserting security bugs in your application.